# How to add a class to an ID if an <h2> tag on a page equals a certain string of text?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use Javascript to add a class or in-line CSS to a specific ID, but only IF the `<h1>` tag on the page contains an EXACT MATCH of a specific word or words within an array.

I'm hiding a div on the page, and only want it to show when  tags are equal to a specific word or to specific words. Below is what I got to work, but without using an array.

```
$('h1').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'exampleText') {
        $('#bannerIMG').addClass("showID");
    }
});
```

I also tried using :contains, which worked, but it didn't show the div based on EXACT matches. For example, the div would show for h1 tags containing 'Example Text' and 'Example', but I only wanted it to show for h1 tags that equaled 'Example Text'

```
var exampleArray = ['text1', 'text2', 'multiple words1', 'multiple words2'];

    $('h1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == exampleArray) {
            $('#bannerIMG').addClass("showID");
        }
    });
```

I want an array with a list of h1 tags that contain the names of the  different pages, and I want a certain div to show only on the pages I have listed in the array. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: One thing to consider, use a class to hide the element, then use whatever logic to remove the class. Why? If you have anything other than `display:block` it's easier to remove a class with `display:none` than guess the right value for the `display` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `includes()` or `indexOf()` to do the checking.

The `trim()` method removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

```js
var exampleArray = ['text1', 'text2', 'multiple words1', 'multiple words2'];

$('h1').each(function() {
  if (exampleArray.includes($(this).text().trim())) {
    $('#bannerIMG').addClass("showID");
  }
});
```

```css
.showID {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h1>
  text1
</h1>

<div id="bannerIMG" style="display:none;">ABC</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding `return false` in your `if` statement to the `each` loop stops when a match is found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works great for Chrome and Firefox, but not at all for IE. I'm seeing that includes isn't supported in IE, so I went to try indexOf instead. Now in all browsers, either the wrong banner shows, or they both show. Any idea what's going on?